# Issue with adding Linq Where clause containing a string Contains test

Tags: c#, string, linq, where-clause

Okay, this behavior has me really stumped. I have an IQueryable list that I'm trying to add Where clauses to check whether a string field contains a substring. When I hardcode the search string like this:

```
sourceList = sourceList.Where(license => license.FileNumber.Contains("S0"))
```

it works as expected and generates the internal query from inspecting sourceList in the Visual Studio debugger:

```
{SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id], [Extent1].[FileNumber] AS [FileNumber],
    [Extent1].[LegalLocation] AS [LegalLocation]FROM [dbo].[Licenses]
    AS [Extent1]WHERE [Extent1].[FileNumber] LIKE N'%S0%'}
```

The strange thing happens when I set the search value from a variable like:

```
string testString = "S0";
sourceList = sourceList.Where(license => license.FileNumber.Contains(testString))
```

This generates the internal query:

```
{SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id], [Extent1].[FileNumber] AS [FileNumber],
    [Extent1].[LegalLocation] AS [LegalLocation]FROM [dbo].[Licenses]
    AS [Extent1]WHERE [Extent1].[FileNumber] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~'}
```

Notice the difference in the LIKE part at the end? I am really confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's hoping it's something really stupid. In case it has any relevance, this is for filtering data from an Entity Framework source.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: It is simply passed like a parameter in the 2nd case

Comment: Does the second query return incorrect results or exhibit other unwanted behavior?

Comment: I didn't think it was returning the correct results but that was actually caused by an unrelated issue. I've accepted Brad's solution as it was the most detailed. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you observe the actual query, you'll see `@p__linq__0` is actually assigned the `S0` value, then passed to the query.

```
@p__linq__0 = '%S0%';
... WHERE [Extent1].[FileNumber] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~'
```

Which basically is like:

```
... WHERE [Extent1].[FileNumber] LIKE N'%S0%' ESCAPE N'~'
```

And because it's a parameter, LINQ just takes the precaution and adds the `ESCAPE` clause. It's also a variable instead of a hard-coded constant and any changing value in a LINQ statement is passed as a parameter instead of inserted directly in to the query.

Reference: [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: You're absolutely right Brad, that just shows my newbie status when it comes to Linq:)

Answer (score 1):

The second internal query is just using a parameter in the `LIKE` clause, as expected.

If you are observing different results, it could be because you are passing `"SO"` in one case, and `"S0"` in the other (at least in some of the code in your question).

Comment: Good catch although that wasn't the cause of my confusion, when I tested it was actually all S0. I've fixed it in my post though for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the second case LINQ generates a parameterized query. Consider, if you constrcuted a parameterized query manually using some `DbCommand`:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
     "SELECT * from SomeTable where SomeField like @Param1", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%SomeField value%";
```

so `@p__linq__0` is the name of the parameter generated by linq (whereas in my example it's `@Param1`).

`ESCAPE` keyword is a part of `LIKE` expression (see [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)):

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]
> ```

where

> escape_character
>
> ```
> Is a character that is put in front of a wildcard character to indicate that the    
> wildcard should be interpreted as a regular character and not as a wildcard. 
> escape_character is a character expression that has no default and must evaluate to 
> only one character.
> ```